# Create Trigger in MySQL and Update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need help creating a particular trigger using MySQL. The details for my trigger is given below along with my current statement. However, my statement keeps giving me an error message so I'm doing something wrong. Any assistance would be great! Thanks!

Problem a)  Create a trigger called membership_balance_updates that will capture any updates made to the mem_balance column in membership. The trigger should only capture those transactions in which the member’s balance actually changes. The mem_num, old mem_balance, new mem_balance, user, transaction date should be placed into a membership_balance_audit table.

My Statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER membership_balance_updates
AFTER UPDATE OF mem_balance ON membership
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO membership_balance_audit 
VALUES (mem_mum, old_mem_balance, new_mem_balance, transaction_date, 
transaction_user);
```

[Table "Membership"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHswA.jpg)

Here's the following script to create the membership_balance_audit table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS membership_balance_audit
    (mem_num                   INTEGER,
     old_mem_balance     DECIMAL(10,2),
     new_mem_balance   DECIMAL(10,2),
     transaction_date       TIMESTAMP,
     transaction_user       VARCHAR(50));
```

[Part c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r59HV.png)

Comment: We need the column names for the `membership` and `membership_balance_audit` tables.

Comment: I replaced the last photo with part c (the final part of the problem). Looking at the data in part c, it appears to be some kind of root access information. I don't know where that could come from. I wonder if my teacher made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER membership_balance_updates 
AFTER UPDATE ON membership
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.mem_balance <> OLD.mem_balance THEN
        INSERT INTO membership_balance_audit
            (mem_mum, old_mem_balance, new_mem_balance, transaction_date,
             transaction_user)
        VALUES (OLD.membership_id, OLD.mem_balance, NEW.mem_balance, NOW(),
                CONCAT(OLD.first_name, ' ', OLD.last_name));
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: do the if changed thing

Comment: 1 minute...also we don't really know the column name.z

Comment: ha you goofy guy, but that didn't stop you :P   Off on other cleaning tasks, you got it covered

Comment: Tim, I tried your statement and it gave me an error message that says: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NEW.mem_balance <> OLD.mem_balance THEN         SET mem_num = OLD.mem_num,   ' at line 6

Comment: Try again.  Your original guess was way off.

Comment: Another error message: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 9

Comment: Missing parenthesis and semicolon after the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: I added the parenthesis and semicolon and still an error message: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Comment: How do you intend to populate the `transaction_user` column in the audit table?  There isn't any column in the `membership` table which seems appropriate.

Comment: Yeah something doesn't look right. The problem came directly from class as is. I also added the link photo "Part a and b" on top. Maybe that might help.

Comment: I just updated my answer to use the user first name and last name for the `transaction_user` field in the audit table.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Tim!